# Get all objects from Array in Angular Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, scope

I am trying to get all objects within an array from a scope in angular. I am using jQuery to get the array but I'm not sure how to get each object from the array without having to define it like [0].

`angular.element("#scopes").scope().fixtures;`

This gives me:

`Array[380]`

Which I can then select from but I need to get them all in one go.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "get all objects within an array"? Do you want an array of these objects? If so, how is that array different from the array you can already get? If not, what form do you want them in?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is I want to get at certain parts of the array but I need to return all of them in one go in order to access these certain parts. For example the API that I am using is for football data. I need to get the status of the match e.g. FINISHED or TIMED for each one.

Comment: If I add ```angular.element("#scopes").scope().fixtures.status;``` to it then it becomes undefined however I can access the first one by ```angular.element("#scopes").scope().fixtures[0].status;```. I want a way to access all status at once. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @GarethFrazer Look at my answer, it is exactly what you are needing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** This is how I would implement this solution. Note that it no longer uses any jQuery. It retrieves the data from the API, and then iterates over each item in the array allowing you to do what you want with it. [angular.forEach Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

```
// In your angular controller...
$http({
    url: "myApiUrl",
    method: "GET",
    cache: false,
    params: {
        //whatever API params you want to pass
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.fixtures = response.data;
    $scope.fixtures.forEach(function (element, index) {
        // do what you want - as per your comments...
        console.log("Element: " + index);
        console.log("Status: " + element.status);
        console.log("________________________________");
    });

}, function failureCallback() {
    alert("There was an error retrieving the data!");
});
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. It seems like such a silly question now. Appreciate the quick response.

Comment: @GarethFrazer No worries! If this solution worked for you, feel free to upvote and mark as the accepted answer

Comment: When I use this in the console I can get it working however when using it in my js file it says 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'.

Comment: That likely has to do with a timing issue. If you do not have some sort of trigger for this function, and especially if you do not have it in a document ready function, it has a good possibility of executing before angular has a chance to bind itself to the dom, create the $scope, attach the fixtures array to $scope, etc. etc. So because the code is executing before angular has a chance to do it's thing, it's coming back undefined, and jQuery's $.each is trying to do a .length on undefined, which is why you are getting that error.

Comment: What would you advise is the best way to deal with that then?

Comment: Put this code in the callback function of your API call to get the data. I will update my answer to show what I mean

Comment: @GarethFrazer Done. See if that makes sense for your application

Comment: Thank you so much, I have only recently started with Angular, this makes things a lot clearer for me. Very much Appreciated.

Comment: @GarethFrazer No problem! Here are some resources that may be helpful for you: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-for-the-jquery-developer.html  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, it sounds like you want to map over the results:

```
var statuses = angular.element("#scopes").scope().fixtures.map(function(fixture) {
    return fixture.status;
});
```

However, it feels like you should be able to get this data from your model instead of trying to pull it out of your view.